# android scale zoom too fast crash

Tags: android, crash, zooming, scale

When i scale zoom the up quick and fast then will crash around 5-10 second.

```
private int getTrueHeight(){
    Window window= container.getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
    Log.d(TAG, "True Height is "+ rectgle.height());
    return rectgle.height();

    //return container.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-StatusBarHeight;
}
```

this is the code when scale then call it.

Please give me some advise. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think this part is causing the crash? What does the LogCat say?

Comment: this part call when scale , scroll or zoom. i have set the counting for this part. when i zoom then call 800-2000 times around 10 second then will going to crash.